# The new "Drag and Drop Image" is flaky: often unable to upload image from local machine

Tags: support, images, osx

Upon trying to use the new "Drag and Drop or click here", a Finder window is opened and I select a screenshot.

However about half of the time the following occurs after attempting to upload the screenshot:

[image]

Obviously it does not happen 100% - or I would not have been able to show *this* screenshot!

I am on OS/X Yosemite with Chrome.  Any suggestions?

**SORRY! False alarm!**   The screenshot had failed and the image was only a 5KB white background.  Out of maybe 200 or so uploads I have done to SOF it happened only this one time - just after this new upload process. So I conflated the two.

Comment: @javadba Here is fine. MSE is fine too. Shog has very helpfully alerted me to this post so I'll be looking at it.

Comment: @javadba - don't worry about it.  I retracted the CV.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the updated OP:

**SORRY! False alarm!** The screenshot had failed and the image was only a 5KB white background. Out of maybe 200 or so uploads I have done to SOF it happened only this one time - just after this new upload process. So I conflated the two.

Comment: Got it. Bummer that your screenshots have failed.

Comment: actually i am a bit afraid to delete the question because I (ill-advisedly) already answered it.  SOF does not like deleting answered questions.